# How to create Hold for Video,tap for photos like whatsapp functionality in Ionic 4/5 Using Camera or another plugin

Tags: ionic4, ionic5

How to create Hold for Video, tap for photos like WhatsApp functionality in Ionic 4/5 Using Camera or another plugin
Please help me

[image]

Comment: Do you have some code to start with? What sort of technical issue did you run into attempting to achieve this?

Comment: You can use hammer.js(https://hammerjs.github.io/) to get this behavior. Previous versions of ionic used to ship with hammer.js included. But due to some performance reasons, they will not be including hammer.js with their build anymore.

Another option is to explore ionic Gesture. It is relatively new.. and things might change.. link - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/gesture/index.ts

reference - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19183#issuecomment-524908233